# Microservice and service collaboration

Tags: microservices, dddd

In the context of a Microservice architecture, a single business operation can require collaboration between two or more services.

Suppose we have an Order Management Service and a Product Catalog Service.
When the user adds an order item to an order, the Order Management Service will persist a OrderItem object which have the following attributes among many others :

```
OrderItem 
+ Id
+ ProductId
+ ProductName
```

In order for the Order Management Service to fill the ProductName attribute, we have 4 choices as I see it :

**Choice 1** : ProductName is given by the client app as it probably already has this data from previous requests

**Choice 2** : If the architecture uses an Api Gateway, the gateway will be responsible for retrieving the ProductName from the Product Catalog Service then provide it to the Order Management Service.

**Choice 3** : The Order Management Service will call directly the Product Catalog Service and asks him for the ProductName givent a product id.

**Choice 4** : The Order Management Service has a duplicate (but not exhaustive) product informations in its own database and these datas will be updated each time an update event is received from the Product Catalog Service.

Among these 4 choices, the n°1 seems not ok to me as we can't trust the client to give us a correct and updated value of ProductName.

I would like to have your opinion about what you think the best choice is and why !

Thanks !

Riana

Comment: This is probably better suited for Code Review SE

Comment: @zack6849 in its current form, this post would not be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for CR because it lacks code (and also sounds **hypothetical** - given "_Suppose we have_ ...."). See ["Which Site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Choice 1 : ProductName is given by the client app as it probably already has this data from previous requests

Like you said, it is not the best idea because the client may have stale information. Maybe acceptable if the product information changes infrequently and/or you have a secondary verification at order processing.

> Choice 2 : If the architecture uses an Api Gateway, the gateway will be responsible for retrieving the ProductName from the Product Catalog Service then provide it to the Order Management Service.

IMHO, this is not a good idea. By doing so your domain/business logic will leak into the API Gateway. The gateway now knows the relationship between Orders and Products. This API gateway configuration/scripting will need to be maintained and introduces additional coupling.

> Choice 3 : The Order Management Service will call directly the Product Catalog Service and asks him for the ProductName givent a product id.

This is my preferred choice. Though I do not recommend "direct" synchronous calls. Perhaps a retrieval of the ProductName via a messaging mechanism (message queue, event bus). Chained synchronous calls will reduce the availability of your services. You can find more information at [Microservice Messaging Pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/communication-style/messaging.html).

> Choice 4 : The Order Management Service has a duplicate (but not exhaustive) product informations in its own database and these datas will be updated each time an update event is received from the Product Catalog Service.

Data duplication is generally frowned upon unless there is a really good reason for it. In this case I don't see any. Why bother splitting the databases into two for each of the services yet duplicate the data between them? Also, to have the data updated each time an update event is received indicates that some kind of event/messaging infrastructure is available, in that case, why not just use messaging?

This duplication may be justifiable for high volume, low latency look ups, but it is a slippery slope that may end up with duplicated data all over your services. Imagine the repercussions of a length or type/format change of the ProductName string...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Seth. Choice 3 can be a good one as you said. The drawback I see is that now the Order management service is not really autonomous to accomplish the business operation "order an item". If product catalog is not available then all the business operation will fail .. I know that there is no perfect choice, compromises must be done ..

Comment: I understand because I am struggling with similar dilemmas. I think one way to look at this is think about autonomy from a technical perspective. As long as the interfaces remain the same or backward compatible, the Order Management service should be able to change as much as possible without any dependency on other microservices.

Comment: " if your initial microservice needs data that's originally owned by other microservices, do not rely on making synchronous requests for that data. Instead, replicate or propagate that data (only the attributes you need) into the initial service's database by using eventual consistency (typically by using integration events, as explained in upcoming sections)." quoted from Microsoft documentation on microservices : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture